# Xcode5: link aws4c library

Tags: c++, c, xcode, xcode5, aws4c

I have C++ project in Xcode

I would like to use C library aws4c in it https://code.google.com/p/aws4c/

Here is my **apn.cpp** file:

```
#include "aws4c.h"

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     aws_init(); 

     ...
}
```

In Xcode it looks OK, but when I'm trying to build - get error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "aws_init()", referenced from:
      _main in apn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the right way to link C library to C++ project in Xcode5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this

added

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

to aws4c.h file and it works

Comment: And if I use linux? I have tried it, but it still give me that error

Comment: This also works in Linux as well. I compiled my final application for Linux